# Unable to deploy drool-workbench on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, drools, drools-guvnor

I have a Centos VM on which tomcat is running.
So I was trying to deploy drool-workbench war from

```
http://192.168.56.102:8080/manager/
```

But I have encounter following errors:

```
2014-01-17 17:32:05,279 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR Can't initialize       FileSystemProviders
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.uberfire.java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider:      Provider org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider could not be instantiated:    org.uberfire.java.nio.IOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

2014-01-17 17:32:05,335 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR Failed to setup Repository 'uf-playground'
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public org.uberfire.backend.server.io.ConfigIOServiceProducer.setup() on org.uberfire.backend.server.io.ConfigIOServiceProducer@2c4c74
```

Comment: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` Are you running another service in the same port?

Comment: It can also mean that your firewall is blocking it.

Comment: I already take care of firewall.

Comment: @JAndy: I checked about the port usage , port is free.

Comment: I figured it out finally, drool workbench 6.0.1 have some memory leakage issues. hence whenever you shutdown tomcat. It didn't stop the services related to previous workbench. Hence I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

it is not the tomcat address already bind.... maybe something what you want install or deploy is using the same port than tomcat (not only 8080, but all the ports used by tomcat or another service)